# Problems accessing data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have a problem with angular

I have this function

```
$scope.loadChart=function(){
                $http.get("tabla.php")
                    .success(function(dat){
                    $scope.tabla=dat;
                });
            };
```

so, i tried to access to $scope.tabla[0].id but i cant, i'd already check if $scope.tabla isnt empty and it is ok

Thanks

Comment: What does `dat` return? Can you post that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `JSON.stringify()`

```
$scope.loadChart=function(){
     $http.get("tabla.php")
         .success(function(dat){
              $scope.tabla=JSON.stringify(dat);
          });
     };
```